# Dashed Polyline in Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, polyline, folium

I have an assignment which requires me to make an itinerary on Colaboratory using Folium. I have 8 different locations in Europe linked together with a Polyline. I was trying to make the line dashed but couldn't find a way to...

I am a beginner and couldn't find many solutions. 
The ones i've tried did not work, i have tried things like adding: linestyle='dashed'(i have no idea if that is what i am supposed to do or if i used it correctly, i must have just added it after color='red', --> check script part 1)

Here is my script (it was too long for one picture)
[Script part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMXfu.png)
[Script part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrRun.png)

Here is my map (the red lines are what i tried to get dashed)

My map

[image: My map]

Comment: Share your codes instead of pictures!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `dash_array` argument in [`PolyLine()`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.PolyLine) function:

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[43, 11],
               zoom_start=5)

loc = [(43, 11),
       (48, 13),
       (49, 3),
       (44, 4),
       (45, 6)]

folium.PolyLine(loc,
                color='red',
                dash_array='10').add_to(m)

m
```

and you get:

[image]